# How to add your own completion block after runAction is done in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am new to cocos2d right now I have some action as following:

```
[self.rewardLabel runAction:[CCSequence actionOne:[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:3.5] two:[CCHide action]]];
```

I want to do something after this sequence of actions is done. How can I achieve that since there is a 3.5s duration?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming cocos2d 2.2 for the above snippet. If you use the array constructor for CCSequence, you can build some complex stuff. Here is an example (from my code) of a sequence with a call block :

```
id scaleDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.25 scaleX:0.f scaleY:1.f];
id scaleUp  = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.25 scaleX:1.f scaleY:1.f];
id flip = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{ _normal.flipX=YES;}];
id unflip = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{_normal.flipX=NO;}];
id once = [CCSequence actions:scaleDown,flip,scaleUp,unflip,nil];
id twice = [[once copy] autorelease];
id three = [[once copy] autorelease];
id four = [[once copy] autorelease];
id done = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    _normal.anchorPoint=ccp(0,0);
    _normal.position=ccp(0,0);
}];
id all = [CCSequence actions:once,twice,three,four,done,nil];

[_normal runAction:all];
```